# Multiplication table not working correctly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a multiplication table for 12 using array and for loop but it is just multiplying it to infinity.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number[9];

    number[0] = 1;
    number[1] = 2;
    number[2] = 3;
    number[3] = 4;
    number[4] = 5;
    number[5] = 6;
    number[6] = 7;
    number[7] = 8;
    number[8] = 9;
    number[9] = 10;
    for (int i=1; i++; i <= 11)
    cout << i * number[9]<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Set the size of array to 10: `int number[10];`

Comment: what do you mean multiplying it to infinity. post your output

Comment: The title should be a simple summary of your question, and the question should be written in your question.

Comment: It's a little suspect that you create an array, but only ever read from `number[9]`.

Comment: How does one get "a table of 12" when your array has only 9 elements, you set **10** of these elements, and you (try to) loop 11 times? Where does "12" come into play?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the number that is specified in the array declaration in C++ is not the maximum index but the number of elements. Therefore, `number[9]` is out-of-range for the array `int number[9];`. You have to allocate enough elements.

Secondly, the loop condition should be the middle of the `for` statement and the updating expression should be the right of the `for` statement. They are swapped in your `for` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number[10]; // allocate enough elements

    number[0] = 1;
    number[1] = 2;
    number[2] = 3;
    number[3] = 4;
    number[4] = 5;
    number[5] = 6;
    number[6] = 7;
    number[7] = 8;
    number[8] = 9;
    number[9] = 10;
    for (int i=1; i <= 11; i++) // fix for statement
        cout << i * number[9]<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice the code was only reading from `number[9]`.